# Android text color not working

Tags: android, android-xml

I've used www.android-holo-colors.com to generate a theme for my app. It's correctly applying the new styling to my buttons, however I seem to be unable to change the text color on the buttons.

Here is a button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/my_groups"
        android:id="@+id/myGroups_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="myGroups" />
```

Here is my theme:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
```

Here is my ButtonAppTheme:

```
<style name="ButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
      <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

And my colors_apptheme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="apptheme_color">#ff9800</color>
    <color name="background">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_text">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="list_sub_text">#ff555555</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#ff263248</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#ff7e8aa2</color>
</resources>
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going wrong? Neither color or textstyle is being applied.

Comment: Have you created a `color.xml` file?

Comment: Yes it's there, let me add.

Comment: Maybe try to define the color like this: #FFFFFF

Comment: where do you apply the style to button?

Comment: This is where the button get's applied: `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>`

Comment: Changing it to all caps didn't help.

Comment: FACING SAME PROBLE, Did you find any solution ?? @Difusio

Answer (score 0):

Here is a button style , which can be used to change the text color :

```
 <style name="App_ButtonStyleFooter" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_footer</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/PureWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">5pt</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

When textcolor doesn't work in the style file, just add it to the XML layout file where the element is declared, next example shows a button with white text :

```
<Button
 android:text = "Click me"
 android:textColor = "#ffffff" />
```